# Finding maximum-cardinality independent set with a particular oracle

Tags: algorithms, graphs, reductions

We suppose we have a polynomial algorithm which receives a graph $G$ (any graph) and returns a stable set of $G, SA(G)$ with the following property:

$\alpha(G) − |SA(G)| \leq k$ , for every natural $k$ ($k$ is a constant)

$\alpha(G)$ is the stability number

I need to show that this algorithm can be used to find(in polynomial time) a stable set (of maximum cardinality) in a graph.

I discovered that if I give $k=0$ then we get to this relation. But does that mean that the algorithm finds the stable set with maximum cardinal.

Comment: I don't understand the stated property. Since $SA(G)$ is stable, we know that $|SA(G)|\leq\alpha(G)$. But the fact that $\alpha(G)-|SA(G)|\leq k$ for every natural number $k$ means, in particular, that $\alpha(G)-|SA(G)|\leq 0$, so we deduce that $|SA(G)|=\alpha(G)$ and we're done. Did you mean to give some other property?

Comment: Also, what did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual questions but just answering homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help you.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Voting to close as unclear: the property given still implies that the oracle returns a set of size max-0=max.

Comment: It would make much more sense if the property was assumed for some fixed $k$, not all $k$.

Answer (score 1):

If $k = 0$ then your algorithm outputs a stable set of maximum size. In the general case, try duplicating each vertex $k+1$ times, and see if it helps.